# Java, 2D String Array Filled from JTextFields

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am creating a commercial software and got stuck in place, where I need to fill an Array with information from multiple JTextBox fields.

I created an Array -

```
 public String[][] BookAttributes = new String[BookRows][BookLines];
```

I want to save information added by User from following JTextFields in [BookLines] column for each book, which should auto-increment every time when new book is added to stock.

```
private JTextField tfBookName;
private JTextField tfBookCost;
private JTextField tfBookYearOfPublication;
private JTextField tfBookPublishingHouse;
private JTextField tfBookISBN;
private JTextField tfBookAuthor;
private JTextField tfBookNrOfPages;
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution how to put this all together.

Any Help appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then you are looking to save the `Book` information like `Name`, `Cost` etc. to an array.

But, in the above case you are creating a `2-D String Array` which looks something like this:

```
Location (0,0) of array -> "foo"
Location (0,1) of array -> "bar"
...
...
```

What you actually need is a class say, `Book` which can hold the information regarding the different attributes. Something like as follows:

```
public class Book {

    private String bookName;
    private String bookCost;
    private String bookYearOfPublication;
    private String bookPublishingHouse;
    private String bookISBN;
    private String bookAuthor;
    private String bookNrOfPages;

    /* Constructor, Getter, Setters */
    ...
}
```

Next you can create an array of this class like this:

```
int bookRows = 100;
Book[] booksInfo = new Book[bookRows];
```

And simply code a `for` loop for stroing the different book details as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bookRows; i++) {
    Book book = new Book();

    book.setBookName(tfBookName);
    ...
    ...

    booksInfo[i] = book;
}
```

You can further override the `toString()` method of the `Book` class if you want to print the different attributes of any book by simply using `System.out.println(...)`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder().append("BookName: ").append(bookName)
                              .append(" | Book Cost: ").append(bookCost).toString();
}
```

Comment: @Helvijs What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I tried this, but
 book.setBookName(tfBookName.getText()); 
brings me an error, that I cannot make a  static reference tothe  a non-static method from the type Book ! So Eclipse want me to make setBookName method static (which I don't think need to be static, because it's setter). @user2004685

Comment: @Helvijs Are you doing everything inside the `main()` function?

Comment: No. I already checked, I don't have any static variables or methods involved in this process. I created class Book with setters and getters for all attributes needed. And in different class I am using Book class Object to store all this information in it

Comment: I found the problem, everything works now. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask you one More question Please?  @user2004685

Comment: @Helvijs Sure. Why not. Tell me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132956/discussion-between-helvijs-and-user2004685).